# How can I reverse Coordinate vector and apply transformation to all Data Variables?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have the following Dataset in xarray (see below). I am looking to flip the "latitude" coordinate and consequently apply it to all the Data Variables. Naturally, latitude should go from largest to smallest value (90 to -90), and when I tried to use something like latitude[::-1], it doesn't apply that reversing function to the data variables themselves. I tested this by grabbing the value from TMP_2maboveground[0,50,50] before and after reversing the latitude vector. The values came back the same which can't be possible since they should be two different locations on Earth before and after reversing latitude vector.

In short, how can I reverse the latitude vector and apply it to all the Data Variables?

```
<xarray.Dataset>


Dimensions:              (latitude: 721, longitude: 1440, time: 1)


Coordinates:

* latitude             (latitude) float64 -90.0 -89.75 -89.5 -89.25 -89.0 ...
* longitude            (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0 1.25 1.5 ...
* time                 (time) datetime64[ns] 2016-11-10T12:00:00


Data variables:


   TMP_2maboveground    (time, latitude, longitude) float64 234.9 234.9 ...
   RH_2maboveground     (time, latitude, longitude) float64 96.8 96.8 96.8 ...
   TMAX_2maboveground   (time, latitude, longitude) float64 234.9 234.9 ...
   TMIN_2maboveground   (time, latitude, longitude) float64 234.3 234.3 ...
   UGRD_10maboveground  (time, latitude, longitude) float64 -1.17 -1.16 ...
   VGRD_10maboveground  (time, latitude, longitude) float64 -4.26 -4.27 ...
   PRATE_surface        (time, latitude, longitude) float64 1e-06 1e-06 ...
   DSWRF_surface        (time, latitude, longitude) float64 310.0 310.0 ...
   PRMSL_meansealevel   (time, latitude, longitude) float64 1.024e+05 ...


Attributes:


   Conventions: COARDS
   History: created by wgrib2
   GRIB2_grid_template: 0
```

Thanks

anj

Answer (score 4):

You could also use sortby to achieve that:

```
ds = ds.sortby('latitude', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pulling out the index, sorting it, and then reindexing the dataset on the sorted index?